# Tool like BetterErrors for JRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I would like to use BetterErrors, but my project uses JRuby, which is unsupported by BetterErrors. Is there a alternative to the `better_errors` gem that works on JRuby?

What I want is when I have an error in my app, to be able to see it in the browser and use the REPL from the web.

Comment: Rails 4.2 has web_console which kinda does what you are looking for.  Not sure if it works with jruby or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use [web_console](https://github.com/rails/web-console) which is default in [Rail 4.2](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#web-console) .

Altough the support for jRuby is still experimental, as you can see in the README of the project:

There is an experimental JRuby 1.7 support. See Installation section for more information.

If you are running JRuby, you can get experimental support with adding a pre-release version of binding_of_caller.

```
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'binding_of_caller', '0.7.3.pre1'
end
```

After you save the Gemfile changes, make sure to run bundle install and restart your server for the Web Console to kick in.